# Bayes theorem on uniform random variables

Tags: probability

I have the following problem: $X \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ and $Y|X\sim \text{Uniform}(0,X)$. What's the distribution of $X|Y$?

My guess is that it should be $X|Y \sim \text{Uniform}(Y,1)$.

To solve this problem I was thinking of using Bayes theorem:
$$
f(X|Y=y) = \frac{f(Y|X=x)f(x)}{f(y)}
$$
and check if it is equal to $\frac{1}{1-y}$. The only problem is that I can not compute $f(y)$. In fact:
$$
f(y) = \int_0^1f(x,y)dx = \int_0^1 f(y|x)f(x)dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} dx = +\infty
$$
So I guess that the pdf of Y does not exist.

How can I proceed? Thank you for any insight!

Comment: The support of the joint distribution is $0 < y < x < 1$, so the integration limit is...

Comment: You're right! So $f(y)$ is actually:

$$
f(y) = \int_y^1 f(x,y)dx = \int_y^1 \frac{1}{x} dx = -\log(y) \qquad y\in[0,1]
$$

Then:
$$
f(X|Y=y) = \frac{f(Y|X=x)f(x)}{f(y)} = -\frac{\frac{1}{x}\cdot 1}{\log(y)} = -\frac{1}{x\log(y)} \qquad x \in [y,1]
$$

is it correct? Is it a known distribution?